# Repeat or wrap texture (DirectX 9)

Tags: textures, directx

Sure there's something I'm missing about wrap/repeat textures in D3D 9.  I've tried setting the sampler in the shader, i.e. :

```
sampler DiffuseSampler = 
sampler_state
{    
    Texture = <DiffuseMap>;

    MipFilter = NONE;
    MinFilter = POINT;
    MagFilter = POINT;

    AddressU = WRAP;    // Repeat on X
    AddressV = WRAP;    // Repeat on Y.
};
```

, and I've also tried doing it in code before I render the object:

```
device->SetSamplerState(D3DVERTEXTEXTURESAMPLER0, D3DSAMP_ADDRESSU, D3DTADDRESS_WRAP);
device->SetSamplerState(D3DVERTEXTEXTURESAMPLER0, D3DSAMP_ADDRESSV, D3DTADDRESS_WRAP);
device->SetSamplerState(D3DVERTEXTEXTURESAMPLER0, D3DSAMP_MAGFILTER, D3DTEXF_POINT);
device->SetSamplerState(D3DVERTEXTEXTURESAMPLER0, D3DSAMP_MINFILTER, D3DTEXF_POINT);
device->SetSamplerState(D3DVERTEXTEXTURESAMPLER0, D3DSAMP_MIPFILTER, D3DTEXF_NONE);
```

I thought there might be something screwy with my texture coordinates too, so I hard coded them to be 0.0, 0.0 on the left and 2.0, 2.0 bottom right.  I expected x 2 repeat but got a similar result to the screenshot, with the texture top left and then what looks like clamp across the rest of the image.

What mistake have I made here? (Note that the screenshot isn't the 0.0, 0.0 -> 2.0, 2.0 experiment I did, it's the general case I get as I'm panning my image around).

[image: Here's a screenshot of the resulting image (it's just a checker texture)]

Comment: You are setting a sampler for the vertex shader in the second piece of code is this what you want?

Comment: In the vertex shader?  No, the only place the sampler is used is in the pixel shader.  I think I see what you're getting at here... that's for vertex texture fetch isn't it.  Hmmmm...

Comment: D3DVERTEXTEXTURESAMPLER0 is indicating you are setting it to the first sampler slot of the vertex shader state.

Comment: OK, not sure whether to delete this question as unbelievably stupid or ask you to add that as the answer so I can give it a cookie.  It now works as I changed it to 0.  I need to pay attention to what I copy and paste from the internet :p.  Thanks János

Comment: No problem I think this question can stay on the site, I am gonna answer it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you are setting a sampler for the vertex shader stage (D3DVERTEXTEXTURESAMPLER0 means the first slot) but you want to use it in your pixel shader. You should change it to null.